# A question related to the power of a matrix

Tags: matrices, contest-math

IIT-JEE (2016, Adv) asked a question, if $$P=\begin{pmatrix} * & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 1 & 0 \\ 16 & 4 &1 \end{pmatrix}~~~~(1)$$
where, the value of the  '$*$' was $1$ and a matrix $Q$ was defined such that $ Q=P^{50}-I$. This good question asked one to find the value of $$\frac{q_{32}+q_{31}}{q_{21}}~~~~~(2)$$ The expected answer is 103.

By mistake I mis-read the $*$ as $2$. It turned out to be even more interesting a problem. The question here is: What is the value of (2) if $*$ is taken to be $2$ in (1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $p_{11}=2$, the Jordan form of $P$ is $J=\pmatrix{2&0&0\\ 0&1&1\\ 0&0&1}$.
Therefore $J^k=\pmatrix{2^k&0&0\\ 0&1&k\\ 0&0&1}$. So, we may express $J^{50}$ as $aI+bJ+cJ^2$, where
\begin{aligned}
a+2b+4c&=2^{50},\\
a+b+c&=1,\\
b+2c&=50.
\end{aligned}
Solving this system of equations, we get
$$
\pmatrix{a\\ b\\ c}
=\pmatrix{1&2&4\\ 1&1&1\\ 0&1&2}^{-1}\pmatrix{2^{50}\\ 1\\ 50}
=\pmatrix{1&0&-2\\ -2&2&3\\ 1&-1&-1}\pmatrix{2^{50}\\ 1\\ 50}
=\pmatrix{2^{50}-100\\ 152-2^{51}\\ 2^{50}-51}.
$$
Since $J$ is similar to $P$, we have $P^{50}=aI+bP+cJ^2$ as well. Therefore
$$
Q=P^{50}-I=(2^{50}-101)I+(152-2^{51})P+(2^{50}-51)P^2.
$$
As
$$
P^2=\pmatrix{4&0&0\\ 12&1&0\\ 64&8&1},
$$
we finally obtain
\begin{aligned}
q_{21}&=(152-2^{51})(4)+(2^{50}-51)(12)=2^{52}-4,\\
q_{31}&=(152-2^{51})(16)+(2^{50}-51)(64)=2^{55}-832,\\
q_{32}&=(152-2^{51})(4)+(2^{50}-51)(8)=200\\
\end{aligned}
and
$$
\frac{q_{32}+q_{31}}{q_{21}}=\frac{2^{55}-632}{2^{52}-4}\approx8.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $P=I+R,$ where $$R=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ a & 0 & 0 \\ a^2 &a & 0 \end{pmatrix} \implies R^2=R^3=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\ a & 0 & 0 \\ 2a^2 &0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \implies P^{n+1}=P^2, n\ge 1. $$
By binomial expansion 
$$P^n=(I+R)^n=I+n R+ {n \choose 2} R^2+ {n\choose 3} R^3+.....+{n \choose n} R^n$$
$$\implies Q= P^n-I=nR+R^2[2^n-n-1]= \begin{pmatrix} 2^n-1 &0 & 0 \\ a(2^n-1) & 0 & 0 \\ a^2(2^{n+1}-n-2] & an & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\implies F=\frac{q_{31}+q_{32}}{q_{21}}=\frac{(2^{n+1}-n-2)a+n}{(2^n-1)}$$
For $n=50, a=4$, we get $F\approx 8$.

Comment: +1 This is nice.

Comment: @user1551 Thanks for the appreciation.